# nodeJS asynchronous processing

Tags: node.js, sockets

```
mCon = false;
 
function login()  {
    var sCmd = "...";
    mCon = false;
    SendCmdSocket(sCmd);
 
    console.log("### mCon : " + mCon); <-- Here
}
 
function SendCmdSocket(sCmd)  {
    var success = socket.write(sCmd);
}
 
socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
    OnReceive(chunk);
});
 
function OnReceive(chunk) {
    mCon = true;
}

login();
```

---

How do I get the mCon value to be true when I record console.log?

I want to proceed with the code after receiving the socket result.

Answer (score 0):

try this one hope so it'll help you

```
mCon = false;

async function login()  {
var sCmd = "...";
mCon = false;
await SendCmdSocket(sCmd);

console.log("### mCon : " + mCon); <-- Here
}

async function SendCmdSocket(sCmd)  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      socket.write(sCmd)
     if(mCon){
       resolve()
      }
    })
 }

socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
OnReceive(chunk);
});

function OnReceive(chunk) {
mCon = true;
}

login();
```

Comment: it's still false.. THX

Comment: I have update the code please try and let me know

Comment: Error Occurred.. 

(node:176084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: socket.write(...).then is not a function

Comment: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:176684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: (node:176684) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I have updated the code please try this one.